# dc.js - ordering function not working for rowchart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

'ordering' function is not working in dc.js for rowchart. I am getting ordering is not a function error. May I know the reason? How to resolve it?

Comment: Hmm - perhaps you are calling it after a function which does not return the chart? Opening the dc.js main page in the debugger, I am able to call `dayOfWeekChart.ordering`.

Comment: please show some code!